# Is there a collection of consistent and nice document icons (e.g. HTML, ZIP, PDF)?

Tags: macos, user-interface, icons, ios, file-type

I am looking for a collection of consistent, nice looking, system neutral document icons. For example, if you check the entry of [PDF file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF) or the [ZIP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) in wikipedia you find at right side a document icon for the respective file. However, these icons are neither free nor have a consistent design. Systems like OS X, Windows, KDE come with a set of consistent designs, but I assume they are not free.

It would be OK for me to buy a license for a set of icons. For example you find such sets on iStockphoto.com, but usually the set contains only a very limited number of file types / mime type (say .txt, .html, .css, .pdf, .doc., .xls, .ppt, .zip).

The reason why I am asking is that I want to display such icons in my [iPhone App](http://www.christian-fries.de/iphone/serialmail/) and iOS itself does not provide these icons. Of course, for this application the icons should follow the iOS icon design guidelines (there is a nice article on the icon design philosophy (e.g. viewing angle, etc.) for OS X in the [Apple OS X HIG](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIcons/XHIGIcons.html)).

Answer (score 0):

There are somme collection at the [openicon libray](http://openiconlibrary.sourceforge.net/gallery2/?./Icons/mimetypes). While not perfect, most of the collections are internaly consistant. Can't make any assumption about suitablilty with apple design, however.

There is also the [cristal clear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/commons:Crystal_Clear) collection

Regards
Guillaume